# mongodb distinct of groupby multiple keys

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to query mongoDB to fetch data aggregation (group, match, last). Here is my document:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "from" : "a",
    "to" : "b",
    "message" : "a to b",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:42:32.789Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:42:32.789Z")
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "from" : "a",
    "to" : "c",
    "message" : "a to c",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:43:32.789Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:43:32.789Z")
}
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "from" : "b",
    "to" : "c",
    "message" : "b to c",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:44:32.789Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:44:32.789Z")
}
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "from" : "a",
    "to" : "c",
    "message" : "a to c2",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:45:32.789Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:45:32.789Z")
}
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "from" : "b",
    "to" : "c",
    "message" : "b to c2",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:46:32.789Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:46:32.789Z")
}
```

Now, i want to **get one document with recent to-from combination**. Example:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "from" : "a",
    "to" : "b",
    "message" : "a to b",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:42:32.789Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:42:32.789Z")
}
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "from" : "a",
    "to" : "c",
    "message" : "a to c2",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:45:32.789Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:45:32.789Z")
}
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "from" : "b",
    "to" : "c",
    "message" : "b to c2",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:46:32.789Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:46:32.789Z")
}
```

I've tried this:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$match:{$or:[{"from":"552e5d7b62c6a4c67093be5d"},{"to":"552e5d7b62c6a4c67093be5d"}]}})
```

Any help with code is appreciated.

Comment: @chridam its a typo. Question updated. Please consider _id, createdAt, updatedAt as a unique keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following aggregation pipeline to get the desired results:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$sort": {
            "updatedAt": -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "to": "$to",
                "from": "$from"                
            },
            "id": { "$first": "$_id" },
            "message": { "$first": "$message" },
            "createdAt": { "$first": "$createdAt" },
            "updatedAt": { "$first": "$updatedAt" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id" : 0,
            "id": 1,
            "from" : "$_id.from",
            "to": "$_id.to",
            "message": 1,
            "createdAt": 1,
            "updatedAt": 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Any quick way to fetch and replace from and to keys from different collection?
Eg: {
    "_id" : 4,
    "from" : {id:"a","name":"a"},
    "to" : {id:"c","name":"c"},
    "message" : "a to c2",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:45:32.789Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-06-06T16:45:32.789Z")
}

Comment: @Prasad.CH Sounds like a good question, can you create a new question for that?